# Problem trying to implement Matlab code in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy, quad

I have a piece of code in Matlab (see below) that works well:

```
clc; clear all;
f = 8500;
c0 = 343;
rho = 1.225;
omega = 2*pi*f;
k = omega/c0;
Z = -426;

lx = 0.1;
ly = 0.1;
nx = 50;
ny = nx/2;

integrand1 = @(x,y,kx) real(((exp(1i*(kx*x + sqrt(k.^2 - kx.^2).*abs(y))))./sqrt(k.^2 - kx.^2)));
integrand2 = @(x,y,kx) imag(((exp(1i*(kx*x + sqrt(k.^2 - kx.^2).*abs(y))))./sqrt(k.^2 - kx.^2)));
Gz = @(x,y) integral(@(kx)integrand1(x,y,kx), -100*k, 100*k, "AbsTol", 1e-4) + 1i*...
            integral(@(kx)integrand2(x,y,kx), -100*k, 100*k, "AbsTol", 1e-4);
Test = Gz(lx,ly)
```

But I need to implement it in Python. I tried to use the same approach with lambda expressions to define my functions as functions handle, but unfortunately, it's not working and I am getting errors. These is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f = 8500       
rho = 1.225        
c0 = 343          
omega = 2*np.pi*f   
k = omega/c0       
Z = -426           

Lx = 0.1                       
Ly = 0.1                       
nx = 50                        
ny = int(nx/2)                  


integrandReal = lambda kx, x, y: np.real(((2*np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))
integrandImag = lambda kx, x, y: np.imag(((2*np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))

integral = lambda x, y: integrate.quad(integrandReal, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y)) + 1j*integrate.quad(integrandImag, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y))

G = integral(Lx,Ly)
```

These are the errors:

```
runfile(XYZ/'untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/XYZ ')
/Users/XYZ/untitled0.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  integrandReal = lambda kx, x, y: np.real(((2*np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))
/Users/ /untitled0.py:32: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  integral = lambda x, y: integrate.quad(integrandReal, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y)) + 1j*integrate.quad(integrandImag, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y))
/Users/XYZ/untitled0.py:30: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  integrandImag = lambda kx, x, y: np.imag(((2*np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(np.sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/XYZ/untitled0.py", line 34, in <module>
    G = integral(0.1,0.1)

  File "/Users/XYZ/untitled0.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    integral = lambda x, y: integrate.quad(integrandReal, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y)) + 1j*integrate.quad(integrandImag, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'
```

Any help is more than welcomed.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"... it's not working and I am getting errors."* Whenever your problem involves errors, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the errors I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scipy.integrate.quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple, not a number, so you should select the first return from it which is the numerical result.

and using np.sqrt will return nan on negative input, you should instead use [numpy.lib.scimath.sqrt](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.scimath.sqrt.html#numpy.lib.scimath.sqrt) as it can handle negative inputs and return complex numbers as shown below.

```py
from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt
integrandReal = lambda kx, x, y: np.real(((2*sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))
integrandImag = lambda kx, x, y: np.imag(((2*sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z)/(sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*Z + omega*rho))*((np.exp(1j*(kx*x + sqrt(k**2 - kx**2)*y)))/(sqrt(k**2 - kx**2))))

integral = lambda x, y: integrate.quad(integrandReal, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y))[0] + 1j*integrate.quad(integrandImag, -100*k, 100*k, args=(x,y))[0]
```